# manipulation of csv format in python files

Tags: python-2.7, list, csv, matrix

I have combined two lists using zip syntax. When I saved it in csv format, whole data are stayed in one cell of excell. what's that i want is: each element of zipped file should be stay on each row.

This is my code:

```
list_of_first_column=["banana","cat","brown"]
list_of_second_column=["fruit","animal","color"]

graph_zip_file=zip(list_of_first_column,list_of_second_column)
with open('graph.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(graph_zip_file)
```

what I want in csv format:

```
banana,fruit
cat,animal
brown,color
```

Comment: Replace `writer.writerow(graph_zip_file)` with `writer.writerows(graph_zip_file)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two ways of doing this, assuming that you're using the `csv` module. You can either use `writer.writerows`:

```
list_of_first_column = ["banana", "cat", "brown"]
list_of_second_column = ["fruit", "animal", "color"]

graph_zip_file = zip(list_of_first_column, list_of_second_column)
with open('graph.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(graph_zip_file)
```

Or, you can use `writer.writerow` and a `for-loop`:

```
list_of_first_column = ["banana", "cat", "brown"]
list_of_second_column = ["fruit", "animal", "color"]

graph_zip_file = zip(list_of_first_column, list_of_second_column)
with open('graph.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in graph_zip_file
        writer.writerow(row)
```

They both should return the same thing, which is what you've indicated as your desired output.

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: I changed writrow to writeros and it have worked. Thank a lot